# Adding top and bottom sections to IFRAME

Tags: html, css, iframe

I currently have an iframe that's setup to cover most of my webpage with the link to it is click on.  Right now I have a top section to the iframe that shows my website's logo and a button to close it.  This is the code I'm using for that:

```
<div id="iframe1_div" class="iframe1">

    <div class="iframe1_points" id="iframe1_points">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="50px">
        <tr>
        <td width="110px" align="center"><img src="http://mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Website TItle" /></td>
        <td>Website Name</div></td>
        <td width="50px" align="center"><a href="#;" class="close"><img src="http://mysite.com/close.png" class="noborder" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <iframe id="iframe1_self" style="width:100%;height:100%;" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

This is the CSS associated with it:

```
.iframe1{display: none;background: #FFFFFF;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;float: left;position: fixed;top: 50%; left: 50%;z-index:99999;}

.iframe1_points{display:none;background:#505469;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:bottom;color:#f0f0f0;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;}
```

Now here's the more tricky part that I can't figure out.  I'm trying to add a section to the bottom of the iframe just like I have at the top and need it to be 64px high instead of 50 px like the top.

So, I tried replicating what was done at the top of the and just modifying the height to 64px and adding it below like this:

```
<div id="iframe1_div" class="iframe1">

    <div class="iframe1_points" id="iframe1_points">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="50px">
        <tr>
        <td width="110px" align="center"><img src="http://mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Website TItle" /></td>
        <td>Website Name</div></td>
        <td width="50px" align="center"><a href="#;" class="close"><img src="http://mysite.com/close.png" class="noborder" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <iframe id="iframe1_self" style="width:100%;height:100%;" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <div class="iframe1_points" id="iframe1_points">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="64px">
        <tr>
        <td width="110px" align="center"><img src="http://mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Website TItle" /></td>
        <td>Website Name</div></td>
        <td width="50px" align="center"><a href="#;" class="close"><img src="http://mysite.com/close.png" class="noborder" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

However, the problem is that now both the top and bottom sections stretch off the page and only show about half of what they should.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...  Thanks!

Comment: Page layouts using frames and tables went out of use 10 years ago.

Comment: It's actually not for viewing my own website, it's for viewing other websites that are linked to from my site without actually leave mine.

Comment: I see problems with your html - first, you should be using css instead of width, height, cellspacing, cellpadding and align attributes, and you have two ids that are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a redev which include your tables, but the rest of the HTML is a bit different to your original. I do hope the result is what you were after.

html part

```
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="controls">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="110px" align="center"><img src="http://mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Website TItle" /></td>
                        <td>Website Name </td>
                        <td width="50px" align="center"><a href="#;" class="close"><img src="http://mysite.com/close.png" class="noborder" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <iframe src="http://ebay.com/">
                &nbsp;
            </iframe>
            <div id="bottom">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="110px" align="center"><img src="http://mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Website TItle" /></td>
                        <td>Website Name </td>
                        <td width="50px" align="center"><a href="#;" class="close"><img src="http://mysite.com/close.png" class="noborder" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

css part

```
<style>
    div {border: 1px solid red;display: block;}
    #container {border: 1px solid blue;}
    #controls {height: 50px;}
    iframe {width: 100%;height: 500px;}
    #bottom {height: 64px;overflow: hidden;}
    table{width:100%;padding:0;}
</style>
```